# MVC5 Application not Debugging Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very weird problem.

I've been creating my application and building it and running it. Chrome pops up with its tab and the page loads.

The last things I can remember installing before the app went haywire is Unity.

So now, I build, I click run in Chrome and the VS doesn't show any pages. The IIS express is running to point where I can query for pages like `Home/Index` but when I query my `JsonResult` `Blog/Blogs` I get a 500 error. I've used fiddler and I can hit the standard URLs but not my JsonResult.

Usually if you're on a page editing it, then you hit F5, chrome will load up that page in the browser. VS isn't doing that anymore.

The only thing I can pin it down to is Unity.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the last thing I added: Unity.

Just as an FYI, the reason no errors were coming back is because none of the controllers serving up my pages had an interface injected into them.

The only controller that had an interface injected into it was the toolbox controller and that was getting accessed via this JSON call. The response that was coming back was a HTML page but you could only view that in the Chrome network tab of the console.

Answer (score 1):

If in the Fiddler response you cannot pinpoint the exact reason why your server returned 500 error you may try debugging your code. So start by enabling all errors. In VS use <kbd>Ctrl+D+E</kbd> and then make sure that `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` is selected:

[image]

Now <kbd>F5</kbd> into your application, click `Continue` on all potential exceptions you don't recognize, and then in the browser navigate to the controller action that unleashed the 500 error. Chances are that the debugger will pinpoint you to the precise reason of this unhandled error.

NOTE: Don't forget to turn off the breaking on all `Common Language Runtime` exceptions settings once you have identified the problem or you might get flooded with lots of verbose errors.

NOTE2: Usually you don't need to resort to this heavy debugging artillery, just by inspecting the error response in Fiddler/Web developer toolbar of your webbrowser, you could come to the conclusion.

Comment: I'm not getting any CLR exceptions. Still getting 500

Comment: I found the error, can't believe I didn't get this before....... It's because one of my interfaces isn't registered! thanks though